# How to Pass Repetitive Values to Different Functions in a Compact Way in C++

Tags: c++

In my C++ game project, I have several functions that require passing multiple structs representing game entities as inputs. This leads to repetitive and verbose code.Is there a more compact way to pass these repeated values to different functions efficiently in C++?

Here is example of two game functions that have very similar inputs and the arguments are repeated many times in the code .
I feel like this makes the code messy .

```
void gameSaver(const int n,
               const GameData &gameData,
               vector<Bullet> &bullets,
               const vector<Dart> &dart, const vector<Striker> &striker, const vector<Wraith> &wraith, const vector<Banshee> &banshee,
               const SpaceShip &spaceship);

// read game from file
int gameLoader(int &n,
               GameData &gameData,
               vector<Bullet> &bullets,
               vector<Dart> &dart, vector<Striker> &striker, vector<Wraith> &wraith, vector<Banshee> &banshee,
               SpaceShip &spaceship);
```

Comment: Wrap them in a class since they seem to all be related?

Comment: It's hard to say anything about refactoring without knowing the whole code and the meaning of these functions. First thing that comes to mind is that there should be a class `Game` that has methods `void save() const` and `int load()`, with the parameters as data members. But without knowing more, it's a wild guess if this is even possible.

Comment: I mean, vectors of 7 different specific kinds of things is a sign of a possible problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a wrapper `class` or `struct` that contains the arguments, and pass that wrapper as a single argument

For example,

```
//   previous definitions of GameData, Bullet, .....

struct GameContext
{
    int n;
    GameData gameData;
    std::vector<Bullet> bullets;
    std::vector<Dart> dart;
    std::vector<Striker> striker;
    std::vector<Wraith> wraith;
    std::vector<Banshee> banshee;
    SpaceShip spaceship;
};

void gameSaver(const GameContext &data)
{
     // save data.n
     // save data.bullets
     //   ... 
}

int gameLoader(GameContext &data)
{
     // load data.n
     // load data.bullets
     //   ... 
     return some_value;
}
```

A couple of notes:

- Your code, as you gave it, is relying on `using namespace std` being in effect.   There are plenty of explanations online explaining why that is a bad idea  (the disadvantages are much larger than perceived advantages due to saving on typing).
- You can't necessarily assume that `gameSaver()` will work without errors.   I suggest it needs to return an `int` as well.